# Running ordered tests in Visual Studio 11

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, ordered-test

I can't run Ordered Tests in Visual Studio 11. As [pointed out in a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rubel/archive/2012/03/17/visual-studio-11-beta-changes-in-web-performance-test-load-test-workflow.aspx), the Test View window has been removed in that particular version, so I can't load see my tests anywhere.

I decided to do some research and stumbled upon [one specific resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in particular. However, the [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on that page don't seem to work for me. What do I do?

When I open the Test Explorer window, I see no tests. When I hit "Run all", nothing runs. I can't even see my individual unit tests.

If I right-click my test project and hit "Run unit tests", it all works just fine.

I have ReSharper EAP 7 installed, but I'm not sure wether or not that really makes a big difference.

It should be noted that I see the following in my output window when clicking "Run all tests" through the Test Explorer. [image]

For those who can't read that small text, here's the basic output.

> ------ Discover test started ------
>
> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.
>
> ========== Discover test finished: 26 found (00:00:03.2335529) ==========
>
> ------ Run test started ------
>
> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.
>
> ========== Run test finished: 0 run (00:00:00.0979866) ==========

### Edit

It seems that if I make a new solution and add my test project to that solution, it runs just fine. It doesn't compile, but the tests are found in the Unit Test Explorer.

However, in the original solution, if I unload every project except a brand new Unit Test Project, it doesn't even detect those test methods.

Making a new solution is not an option for me. I have so many dependencies and projects in that solution that it would be a shame to embed them all again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a new solution and adding all the existing projects to that solution again. Very strange.